# Perl Regex regular expression to split //

Tags: regex, perl, split

I went through s'flow and other sites for simple solution with regex in perl.

```
$str = q(//////);#
```

Say I've six slash or seven, or other chars like q(aaaaa)

I want them to split like `['//','//']`,

I tried `@my_split = split ( /\/\/,$str);` but it didn't work

Is it possible with regex?

Reason for this question is, say I have this domain name:

`$site_name = q(http://www.yahoo.com/blah1/blah2.txt);`

I wanted to split along single slash to get 'domain-name', I couldn't do it. 
I tried

`split( '/'{1,1}, $sitename);` #didn't work. I expected it split on one slash than two.

Thanks.

Comment: So you have a string like `aaaaaa` (six) and you want to break it up into strings `aa`, `aa`, `aa` ... (so, break in pairs of consecutive chars) ... correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your general question, but if you just want to pull the domain out of a URL, something like `/:\/\/([^\/]+)/; print $1;` would work. This looks for `://`, then takes as many non-slash characters as it can after it.

Comment: "_wanted to split along single slash to get 'domain-name'_" -- what does that mean?  (And how does it relate to double things from earlier in the question?)  Can you give example -- what do you need from that `$site_name`?  And can you generally clarify the question, please; the more I read the more I'm confused.

Comment: `@my_split = split( /\/\//, $str);` / `@parts = split('/{1,1}', $site_name);`

Comment: you could simply use `\/+` to split on "any number of slashes" - it seems like you don't care to keep them anyway. Keep in mind that would leave you with the first bit ( "http:" ). I would probably remove that first, then split on a single slash (`/\//`).

Answer (score 5):

The question is rather unclear.

To break a string into pairs of consecutive characters

```
my @pairs = $string =~ /(..)/g;
```

or to split a string by repeating slash

```
my @parts = split /\/\//, $string;
```

The separator pattern, in `/.../`, is an actual regex so we need to escape `/` inside it.

But then you say you want to parse URI?

Use a module, please.  For example, there is [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use URI;

my $string = q(http://www.yahoo.com/blah1/blah2.txt);
my $uri = URI->new($string);

say "Scheme: ", $uri->scheme;
say "Path:   ", $uri->path;
say "Host:   ", $uri->host;
# there's more, see docs
```

and then there's [URI::Split](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Split)

```
use URI::Split qw(uri_split uri_join);

my ($scheme, $auth, $path, $query, $frag) = uri_split($uri);
```

A number of other modules or frameworks, which you may already be using, nicely handle URIs.

Comment: Thanks for all your response,

Comment: I tried this again, 

$str = q(//////);

my @parts = split /\/\//, $str;

$"="\n";
print("@parts \n");

Probably I'm doing something wrong, it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: @NalanP  That `$str = q(//////)` is a very specific string.  If you break it up on double slash it ends up with nothing -- because there are _only slashes_, and between each pair of slashes is "nothing" (empty string).  Again: can you clarify what you actually need?   If it is _really_ to break up `q(aaaaaa)` (six) in such a way to get a list `'aa', 'aa` then you have to explain how/why --- how does know which pairs to keep and which to drop.  But I suspect it's not that...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick way to split the full URL into its components:

```
my $u = q(http://www.yahoo.com/blah1/blah2.txt);
my ($protocol, $server, $path) = split(/:\/\/([^\/]+)/, $u);
print "($protocol, $server, $path)\n";
```

h/t @Mike

Answer (score 1):

So it seems you want to simply get the Domain name:

```
my $url = q(http://www.yahoo.com/blah1/blah2.txt);
my @vars = split /\//, $url;
print $vars[2];
```

results:

```
www.yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Well next piece of code does the trick

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %url;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    m|(\wttps{0,1})://([\w\d\.]+)/(.+)/([^/]+)$|;
    @url{qw(proto dn path file)} = ($1,$2,$3,$4);
    print Dumper(\%url);
}

__DATA__
http://www.yahoo.com/blah1/blah2.txt
http://www.google.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/file.ext
ftp://www.server.com/dir1/dir2/file.ext
https://www.inter.net/dir/file.ext
```

Comment: Why do you use `\w` before `ttps`? `{0,1}` is better written `?`, `\d` is already included in `\w` so `[\w\d.]` is better written `\w.`

Comment: Yes, _\w_ includes _\d_ but the author of the post is not aware of this -- and it easier for new perl programmer to understand. Now about **\whttps{0,1}**, if I place **?** -- it didn't work in _Straberry Perl_ when I have tried it. I could put there **.** but it will be confusing for new perl programmer (as it **any symbol** but we expect a letter [fh] could work as well). I took simplest approach to achieve desired result - same result can be achieved by several ways.

Comment: Ah, ok I see you meant **\whttps?** -- yes, it does work but again for originator of the post it would be easier to understand that there can be 0 or 1 **s** in this place. Otherwise I had to refer him to documentation for **regex**. https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html (obviously that author did not taken time to go through the documentation).

Comment: Just for clarification I misread your comment and thought you referred to **(?ttps{0,1})** in this situation **?** does not work.

Comment: As Toto suggested the _regex_ can be simplified to **m|(\wttps?)://([\w.]+)/(.+)/([^/]+)$|**.

Comment: `\wttps?` matches `3ttps` but not `ftp`

Comment: How about `m|([hf]t?ps?)://([\w.]+)/(.+)/([^/]+)$|`? It is more strict and should take care as _ftp_,_http_,_https_. There are more protocols than ftp,http,https - `m|(.+)://([\w.]+)/(.+)/([^/]+)$|` and then analyse $url{proto} to whatever you need and discard if it not what you wanted.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't match `http` and matches `fps`